# How to set Thymeleaf value in combo box?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

My problem is that fetching data is failed.

Vehicle name is not appearing on UI, but data is out in console. How can I solve this?

```html
Vehicle Type:
<select name="example">
  <option value="NONE">...Choose...</option>
  <option th:each="type : ${datalist}" th:value="${type.getName()}"></option>
</select><br/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `th:text="${type.getName()}"` your option attribute